# 20 MB - is it the minimum package size for our puzzle game made with Unity?

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine

We have created a simple puzzle game with Unity. The final package apk size is 20 MB. The size of our graphic and sound assets combined is 6 MB. We have already tried to do optimization as we found some tips on the Internet (before it was 28 MB).

The question is for experienced developers and it is very simple:

Please let us know if 20 MB is the smallest size that we can achieve? If not, then please let us know your opinion what can be the smallest size for this kind of game? It has only one level.

The link of a game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.strategeens.kineticpuzzle

Comment: What are your current Player settings for android platform?

Comment: Be more specific please

Comment: Open menu "Edit", open "Project settings" submenu and select "player" item. Switch to "Android" tab in Inspector", open "Other settings" section and make a screenshot of it.

Comment: Picture link
[link](http://i58.tinypic.com/5aho4j.jpg)

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's reasonable. `Unity3D` has quite a large footprint itself. Depending on the platform it should be even more that 15MB for the engine itself.

You can check [Editor's log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) to see how much memory is taken by your assets, the rest are binary and engine's internal resources.

As a rough measurement, just try to deploy an empty project with a single scene on the desired platform and you'll figure it out.

---

On `Unity 5` they started to modularize a little bit the engine (see this [post](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/06/23/unity5-api-changes-automatic-script-updating/)).
One of the reasons, is space. One of the benefits is that you'll should be able in the future to build only modules relevant to your game (es. no need for physics? don't build `PhysX`).

Answer (score 1):

In your player settings, you can change device filter to `ARMv7` only, which will reduce your build size, but your compatibility with certain devices will suffer. Also, change `Api compatibility level` to `.NET 2.0 subset` and `Stripping level` to `Strip Byte Code` or even `Use micro mscorlib`. [You can read more about these settings in the manual.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html)

However, I must say that 20 Mb is pretty small for Unity application, and is pretty good from a product side of things. If, however, you begin to reach the 50 Mb limit, then you really need to worry. You'll have to implement [OBB split](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html) if you decide to go over 50 Mb limit.